# Get current active browser content into requests.get()

Tags: python, web, python-requests

I am having trouble with a code, which should read content from a website. 
I found a site (https://docs.python-guide.org/scenarios/scrape/) which helped me understand that the module "request" would be my ideal solution, however I am having the problem that I need to get the current active browser content into this code `page = requests.get(url)` because, reloading the page would change the content.

I am using following code to open my browser:

```
def ffox_open(url,download_path,profile_id=""):
    if profile_id =="":
        profile_id = 'bla'
    profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('/scripts/python/config/firefox/'+profile_id)
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", download_path)
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
    profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/csv,application/vnd.ms-excel, application/force-download, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/msword, application/XLS;text/csv, application/XLSX,  application/csv, application/ris, image/png, application/pdf, text/html, text/plain, application/zip, application/x-zip, application/x-zip-compressed, application/download, application/octet-stream")
    profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", False)
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
    browser.get(url)
    return browser


url = 'www.hereismyurl'
browser = ffox_open(url,current_path,ffox_profile)
```

then I interact a bit with the website and would love to use this 
`page = requests.get(url)`

Could you please help me?

Comment: If you have Selenium, isn't requests a bit redundant? Surely there is a way to get the current page source out of webdriver?

Comment: mhhhhh good hint, never tried to read a page with selenium before - what I especially want is getting an ID out of the page, hence I need to read it and save a certain value in a variable -- do you have any page where I could get a SOP from? :)